# ¿Que tipo de queryset puedo hacer, para ordenar tipo de la estrategia en conservador, moderado y arriesgado?

Tags: python, django, sql, django-models

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi clase:

```
class FirFondoDistribucionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Administrador de las distribuciones de dichos fondos
    """
    list_display = ('fondo', 'tipo_distribucion', 'porcentaje', 'is_activo', 'fecha')


admin.site.register(FirFondoDistribucion, FirFondoDistribucionAdmin)
```

Este es mi modelo:

```
class FirFondoDistribucion(models.Model):
    fondo = models.ForeignKey(FirFondo, null=False, blank=False, help_text='Llave foranea de Fondo', related_name='fir_fondo_distribucion')
    tipo_distribucion = models.CharField('Tipo de la estrategia', max_length='5', choices=FIR_TIPO_DISTRIBUCION)
    porcentaje = models.FloatField('Porcentaje', max_length=4, null=False, blank=False)
    is_activo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField('Fecha Creacion', auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

---

[image: imagen con choices]

```
class FirFondoDistribucion(models.Model):
fondo = models.ForeignKey(FirFondo, null=False, blank=False, help_text='Llave foranea de Fondo', related_name='fir_fondo_distribucion')
FIR_TIPO_DISTRIBUCION = (
(0, 'Conservador'),
(1, 'Moderado'),
(2, 'Arriesgado'),)
tipo_distribucion = models.CharField('Tipo de la estrategia', max_length='5', choices=FIR_TIPO_DISTRIBUCION)
porcentaje = models.FloatField('Porcentaje', max_length=4, null=False, blank=False)
is_activo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
fecha = models.DateTimeField('Fecha Creacion', auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

Asi quedo mi modelo, lo intente con todo, vere lo del modelo, por si hay algun problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas hacer ningún `queryset`. Tienes dos opciones:

1. Usar el [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering) en tu modelo a través de la clase `Meta`:

   ```
   class FirFondoDistribucion(models.Model):
       # ...

       class Meta:
           ordering = ['tipo_distribucion']
   ```
2. Usar el [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering) del `ModelAdmin`:

   ```
   class FirFondoDistribucionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       """
       Administrador de las distribuciones de dichos fondos
       """
       list_display = ('fondo', 'tipo_distribucion', 'porcentaje', 'is_activo', 'fecha')
       ordering = ['tipo_distribucion']
   ```

La opción 1 aplica para todas las vistas mientras que la opción 2 aplica solo para el admin de Django.

---

### Actualización

Ahora entiendo que lo que quieres es tener ese orden en específico: `Conservador`, `Moderado` y `Arriesgado`. En ese caso depende de cómo hayas definido tu choices para `FIR_TIPO_DISTRIBUCION`.

Para manejarlo de esa forma podrías usar:

```
FIR_TIPO_DISTRIBUCION = (
    (0, 'Conservador'),
    (1, 'Moderado'),
    (2, 'Arriesgado'),
)
```

Dado que esos valores se guardan en la base de datos como enteros, entonces el orden que necesitas se va a aplicar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero de esta manera, solo toma de forma ascendente, la idea es que al cargar el módulo, quede como conservador, moderado y arriesgado. Seria un ordering custom.

Comment: @MauricioRivas ese orden depende de cómo hayas definido tu `FIR_TIPO_DISTRIBUCION`

Comment: @MauricioRivas actualicé mi respuesta.